# Create checkbox list on the fly with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist

I create a Checkbox list with the following code:

```
function LoadDetours() {
    if ($("#DepartureCityId").val() != "0" && $("#ArrivalCityId").val() != "0") {
        var url = "/Cities/detours?start=" + $("#DepartureCityId").val() + "&end=" + $("#ArrivalCityId").val();

        $.getJSON(url, null, function (data) {

            var topicContainer = $('ul#detourDiv');
            topicContainer.empty();
            $.each(data, function (iteration, item) {
                topicContainer.append(
                    $(document.createElement("li"))
                    .append(
                            $(document.createElement("input")).attr({
                                type: 'checkbox',
                                id: 'detour-' + iteration,
                                name: iteration,
                                value: "aaaaaaa"
                            })
                    )
                    .append(
                            $(document.createElement('label')).attr({
                                'for': 'detour-' + iteration
                            })
                            .text(item)
                    ))

                alert(item);
            });
        });

                }

    }
```

It seems there is no error and code runs, the alert popup shown that I have data in my items but nothing appear on my form, am I missed anything?

Comment: you are missing at lest one `;`

Comment: `;`'s are usually automatically inserted in javascript. OP, can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Based on your profile history, I assume, that with "mvc", you actually meant ASP.NET MVC framework and not the language-independent design pattern.

Comment: <div id="detourDiv">
<ul style="list-style-type: none;"></ul>
</div>

Comment: @MartinAmps - interesting point of view.  I added that as a comment not as an answer.  I think "automatically inserted" would not be considered technically accurate.  But thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Hogan sorry, a bit new to SO :) for a more elaborate explanation you could refer [here](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.9) but in my experience they aren't consistently implemented and there are edge cases, so my intention was just to point out they aren't the issue here.

Comment: @MartinAmps - Awesome link!  I stand corrected. *Technically* they are inserted.  (Comments are exactly that, not answers.  If you have something that is not an answer you put it here.  Otherwise it is really useful to put answers in the answer area, something some users don't do).

Comment: @Hogan heh yeah, I can see why it doesn't sound plausible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed up the syntax and it works for me

(Sorry, it seems I did not save the fiddle) :(

And based on the comment just posted we see what the problem is.

```
<div id="detourDiv"> <ul style="list-style-type: none;"></ul> </div>
```

and

```
<div > <ul id="detourDiv" style="list-style-type: none;"></ul> </div>
```

in my working code.